# Best relational database to store 1 Billion record

Tags: mysql, node.js, indexing, rds, full-text-indexing

I want to store 1 billion record in single table and perform search operation frequently with very limited number of users.

table format

**Registration ID(unique)   |   Name | Age  | Gender  |  Address**

ABC/12/XY/34      |  ABC   | 25   M         | some address goes gere

**Question:**

-Can i use mysql to store 1 billion record and do frequent search on  it

-Backend is on nodejs hosted on aws, is there any tools by aws to make this seamless?

-Registration ID is the unique column what constraints should i apply to make the search faster (hashing or indexing or something else?)

Comment: Best -> opinion based... be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on AWS, give Amazon Aurora (MySQL) a try. Make sure you select an instance type with sufficient RAM so that the cache is big enough for the index. If you're not inserting frequently and just querying then set your Registration ID field as primary key. This will help speed up your queries if you're searching by Registration ID. Although using a huge table is doable if your hardware is up to the task, it is usually better to shard your data into multiple tables. You should try storing those records that starts with "A" in the Registration ID in 1 table, those starting with "B" in another, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL can easily store 1 billion rows in the table, I suggest to go with Aurora, you can use registation_id as the primary key column and add composite indexes as per as query need to speed it up. i.e if you are referencing one column in most of the select queries then keep that column as the first column in the composite index.

Comment: Who's "we" in the "we can easily store 1... billion rows"

Answer (score 0):

Any relational database can handle a billion rows.

Performance problems occur from

- Inadequate indexes -- especially 'composite' indexes
- Poorly formulated queries -- such as hiding indexed columns inside function calls.

If this is a "Data Warehouse" application, "Summary tables" are vital to performance.

In some cases, I ask "Do you really need to keep the data?"  If you would care to describe your dataset, I will elaborate on why you might not need to keep it all.

Are your queries "point queries"?  Example:  Given a single registration_id, get the rest of the data for it. -- This is *very* trivial, and *very* fast, regardless of database engine, table size, etc.

(I have trouble believing you are going to 'register' a billion differen people!)

What about ingestion speed?  Compute how many rows per second will you have to do to reach a billion rows in a reasonable time.

You *must* sketch out your queries, so we can help you design the table(s), indexes, and even the queries to run with a billion rows.